# What is the limit of this summation?

Tags: limits

If $f(0)=0$ and that $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, and $k$ is a positive integer.
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)+f(x/2)+f(x/3)+..+f(x/k)}{x}=?
$$

Comment: What are your own thoughts about this question? It might also be good to edit the math part, it is not perfectly clear on the last formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above Given $f(0) = 0$

So  can write $$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\;,$$ Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

So $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0)$$  similarly $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-f(0)}{\frac{x}{2}-0}\right]\cdot \frac{1}{2} = f'(0)\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\sum^{k}_{n=1}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum^{k}_{n=1}\left[\frac{f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-f(0)}{x}\right] = \left(\sum^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot f'(0)$$